# How to setup DNS for two domain sharing one subnet

Tags: domain-name-system

We have a subnet shared by two domains which has its own DNS servers. Forward lookup zone does not have a problem because the workstations will go and register itself on its respective DNS server. I have problem in setting up the reverse lookup zone. How do I setup the reverse lookup zone so that I can nslookup on any addresses from any domain and I get the correct reply back.

Comment: Which OS is your DNS server running. Which DNS server software are you using ?

Comment: Windows Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand about your request, you want to have a delegation for in-addr.arpa resolution (reverse lookups) at a sub-class level. You might take a look at [this document](http://www.indelible.org/ink/classless/) describing the process in some detail or refer to [RFC 2317](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2317) which describes the IETF best current practice on this topic.

The trouble with your Windows domains would be that you probably let your clients (or DHCP servers) update the reverse lookup zones on your DNS servers - these update mechanisms are unaware of any eventual classless delegation setups and cannot be configured to function correctly in these environments. If you need this, you probably will have to script your DNS servers to "copy" the PTR records within the zone to your CIDR-delegated zone. You can do this using either [dnscmd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778513%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), the ["DnsShell" powershell module](http://dnsshell.codeplex.com/) or the [DNS WMI provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682125%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for the post. I am just learning DNS and this is too complicated for me.

Comment: If you do not have the need for **secure** dynamic updates, you also might consider setting up a single reverse lookup zone (e.g. 0.168.192.in-addr.arpa) in one domain and a [stub zone](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779197(v=ws.10).aspx) pointing to the authoritative one in the other domain - this way dynamic updates as well as queries should hit the authoritative server - no matter which domain they come from. The authoritative in-addr.arpa zone has to be able to accept [non-secure dynamic updates](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780714(v=ws.10).aspx)  as well

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](http://www.winservermart.com/HowTo/RDNS_Setup_Windows.aspx). It explains how to configure a reverse DNS zone on Windows Server.

Also, you need to ask your upstream provider the delegation of the reverse DNS lookup zone for your subnet.

Comment: I have no problem setting the reverse llokup zone.

Comment: My problem is not how to setup a reverse lookup zone. I have one subnet sharing between two domains and I want to combine PTR records for two different domain DNS at one place so that I can do a nslookup and get correct name resolution no matter which domain the client is in. Thank you,